# Is my Network Media List supposed to be empty, in Chrome dev tools?

Tags: google-chrome, developer-tools, embedded-video

I know that it's possible to download embedded video using Chrome dev tools. I did it myself a couple of times a few years ago. However, I'm not sure what's changed. But, I just can't seem to replicate those heady results! In fact, nothing whatsoever shows up in the Network / Media tab anymore.

I'm on a Macbook (Big Sur 11.6), using Chrome Version 96.0.4664.93 (Official Build) (x86_64).

I right-click and Inspect. I select the Network tab and the Media filter. Then I reload the video page and click play on the video. But, the media list doesn't show anything. It's empty every single time. No matter the video, or site visited.

[Screenshot of empty Network-Media list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fbYF.png)

There are always error messages in the console tab, though. Things like:

> DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for
> https:example-url.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404,
> net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

Any idea what I can do to fix this? I'm a technical beginner. So, any help would be much appreciated.

This is the type of thing I would expect to see:

[Example Network list with Media filter on from Azure Friday](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ah7yU.png)

Answer (score 0):

To see the media while it's playing. You just have to press the 'Filter' option which looks like this:

[Click here to see what the filter button looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7VGD.png)